# How can I use a variable as the table name in node-pg?

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

For example I have a query like:

```
      const rows = await db.query(
        "SELECT * FROM $1 WHERE email = $2 AND password = $3",
        [tableName, email, password]
      );
```

It gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, parameterised queries only work for values (instead of literals) but not for [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). You will need to build the SQL string:

```
const rows = await db.query(
  `SELECT * FROM ${db.escapeIdentifier(tableName)} WHERE email = $1 AND password = $2`,
  [email, password]
);
```

<sup>(Assuming the `db` [is a `PgClient`](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/33#issuecomment-575587229))</sup>

If you know the possible values of the `tableName` variable beforehand, you might get away without escaping; if you don't, you better also specify the schema explicitly.