# How can I replace this obviously bad string interpolation with a prepared statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, prepared-statement, node-postgres

Apart from checking that the attributeId is in a list of predefined strings – possible, but in this particular case costly – is there any way to re-write this in a less 'injectable' fashion (since the use of `'${attributeId}'` is actually a field, and not strictly a parameter...):

```
const { tablename, attributeId } = req.params;
  let stmt = `SELECT DISTINCT row_data->'${attributeId}' as ${attributeId} FROM csv_data WHERE source = '${tablename}'`;
  let result;

  try {
    await pool.connect();
    result = await pool.query(stmt);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

  ...

  return res.status(200).json({
    rows: result.rows.map((elt, i, array) => {
      return elt[attributeId];
    }),
    rowCount: result.rowCount,
  });
```

Comment: First thing in the documentation https://node-postgres.com/#getting-started

Comment: Really? JSONB subqueries are the first thing in the documentation? Who knew?

Comment: You don't want a prepared statement, you want a [*parameterised* statement](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query).

Comment: …and don't use `as ${attributeId}` but rather a fixed column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

;-) Actually I do want to use dynamic column names, for a very specific purpose, and strangely that wasn't production code so console.error() is fine. But thanks for your concern.

The solution turns out to be pg-format:

```js
const format = require("pg-format");

const stmt = format(
  "SELECT DISTINCT row_data->%L as %I FROM csv_data WHERE source = %L",
  attributeId,
  attributeId,
  tablename
);
```

Gives me back exactly what I was looking for, as well as handling the escaping:

```js
"SELECT DISTINCT row_data->'state_code' as state_code FROM csv_data WHERE source = 'EQP'"
```

I definitely don't need the `await pool.connect();` though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a prepared statement, you want a [parameterised statement](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query):

```
const { tablename, attributeId } = req.params;
const stmt = 'SELECT DISTINCT row_data->$1 as attribute FROM csv_data WHERE source = $2;';
//                                      ^^                                           ^^
const result = await pool.query(stmt, [attributeId, tableName]);
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

res.status(200).json({
  rows: result.rows.map(elt => elt.attribute),
  rowCount: result.rowCount,
});
```

Also

- don't use a dynamic column name, if you really needed to, you'd have to [escape it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63293051/1048572)
- don't call `pool.connect()` if you want to use a one-shot query instead of a client (that you'd later have to release)
- don't use `try`/`catch` only around the query, and don't `console.error` instead of sending a proper error response

Comment: Your approach doesn't want to work with JSONB column selection sady.

Comment: Why not? What is `attributeId`? Try `$1::text` instead